# getting a list of the top 10,000 facebook fan pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

How can i get a list of facebooks top 10,000 facebook fan pages - ranked by number of likes?

I found this site that lists the top 100: http://fanpagelist.com/

and this company that analysed the top 600,000: http://www.sysomos.com/insidefacebook/

is there a way to get this data programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is basically impossible because you can't search for all pages, you must have some criteria when searching that matches with an indexable column. You can see those indexed columns with a * (Star) next to them on this page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page

As you can see, the 'fan_count' property is listed for a page, but you can't search for every page then rank my the 'fan_count' property.

what you can do, is search within all of your friends fan pages, and return the highest x after sorting.

You can use this query:
Select name, fan_count  FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1== me()) limit 10) ORDER BY fan_count DESC 
On this page: [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) (Click on FQL query)

On this page you can see the top liked pages from a selection of 10 of your friends. If you remove the 'limit 10' from the query you will see the query fail because its too big. You could however list your friends in order, and then cycle through them 10 at a time and collecting all of the results.